# How to properly insert an array to a multidimensional & associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I cannot seem to insert the grandchild array to it's parent-child array correctly. I have this output below for reference:

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "test 1"
    ["url"]=>
    string(1) "#"
    ["child"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Child-ID"]=>
        int(21063)
        ["title"]=>
        string(17) "Case Parts & Mods"
        ["url"]=>
        string(71) "/product-category/case-parts-mods/"
        ["category"]=>
        string(2) "61"
        ["grandchild"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Child-ID"]=>
        int(21026)
        ["title"]=>
        string(15) "Child of Test 1"
        ["url"]=>
        string(1) "#"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "21026"
        ["grandchild"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["GRANDCHILD"]=>
        string(27) "GRAND CHILD OF CHILD TEST 1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(21) "Grand Child of test 1"
        ["url"]=>
        string(1) "#"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "21065"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "test 2"
    ["url"]=>
    string(1) "#"
    ["child"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Child-ID"]=>
        int(21027)
        ["title"]=>
        string(15) "Child of Test 2"
        ["url"]=>
        string(1) "#"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "21027"
        ["grandchild"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "test 3"
    ["url"]=>
    string(1) "#"
    ["child"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I want this **grandchild array** to be insert into the child array key named "grandchild" that it belongs to:

```
array(4) {
        ["GRANDCHILD"]=>
        string(27) "GRAND CHILD OF CHILD TEST 1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(21) "Grand Child of test 1"
        ["url"]=>
        string(1) "#"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "21065"
      }
```

How do you do that properly using array_push()? Here is my logic code for that output:

```
foreach((array)$menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {

                  if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0){ 

                    $parent_id = $menu_item->db_id;
                    $title = $menu_item->title;
                    $url = $menu_item->url;
                    array_push($parent, array("title" => $title, "url" => $url, "child" => array()));
                  }
                  else if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $parent_id) {
                    $child_id = $menu_item->db_id;
                    $catID = $menu_item->object_id;
                    $title = $menu_item->title;
                    $url = $menu_item->url;
                    array_push($parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"], array("Child-ID" => $child_id ,"title" => $title, "url" => $url, "category" => $catID, "grandchild" => array() ));

                  } else if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $child_id) {
                        $catID = $menu_item->object_id;
                        $title = $menu_item->title;
                        $url = $menu_item->url; 

                       array_push( $parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"], array(
                                    "GRANDCHILD" => 'GRAND CHILD OF CHILD TEST 1',
                                    "title" => $title, 
                                    "url" => $url, 
                                    "category" => $catID
                        )); /** I"M HAVING THIS PROBLEM **/
                  }
                  else{

                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer this by the following code below

```
array_push( $parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"][count($parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"] ) - 1]["grandchild"], array(
                                        "GRANDCHILD" => 'THIS IS A GRANDCHILD',
                                        "title" => $title, 
                                        "url" => $url, 
                                        "category" => $catID
                            )
                        );
```

The grandchild now belongs to it's child-parent.

The key answer is below in order to push the arrays accordingly

```
[count($parent[count($parent) - 1]["child"] ) - 1]["grandchild"]
```